# AVAudioPlayer Sound Different between identical devices with identical settings

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, avaudioplayer

I play a sound effect using:

```
-(void)playCorrectSound
{
    NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Yes" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *soundURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: soundFilePath];

    if(! self.myAudioPlayer || ![soundURL isEqual:self.myAudioPlayer.url]){
        self.myAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:nil];
        self.myAudioPlayer.delegate = self;
    }
    [self.myAudioPlayer setVolume:1.0];
    [self.myAudioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [self.myAudioPlayer play];
}
```

I've added this code to three devices, all iPhone 5, all iOS 7.0.6 Two of them play the sound at significantly lower volume than another phone. All System preferences appear the same across all three devices. Would anyone know why one would be so much louder (and how I want it)?